# Rerendering Components' DOM in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to re-render a components HTML in the DOM when I call `this.rerender();` In the following example I have a form that saves data to the server, and after that is done I want to reset the form so users can submit more data. I do not want to individually clear each property (this is only one example, there are other uses besides a form). Currently, when I run `this.rerender();`, it calls methods such as `didRender()` but does not replace the HTML in the DOM.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

**Example:**

route.hbs

```
{{my-component}}
```

my-component.js

```
actions: {
    submit: {
        // save form data to server, etc.
        this.rerender(); // re-render html in DOM
    }
}
```

my-component.hbs

```
<form {{action 'submit' on='submit'>
    {{input id='name' value=name}}
    <button class="btn green" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* rerender the DOM, but also reattaches all variables you've set in your component. A good way for this is to have a variable for the user data on the component that you can replace.

So something like this in your component:

```
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  set(this, 'userData', Ember.Object.create());
},
actions: {
  submit: {
    // save form data to server, etc.
    set(this, 'userData', Ember.Object.create());
  }
}
```

And then in your template instead of `{{input id='name' value=name}}` do `{{input id='name' value=userData.name}}`

I think since we've got glimmer there is no reason to call `rerender` anymore. This method is *not* build to replace or update the DOM, or to be used on a regular use-case in any application. Its only purpose it to fix some very uncommon edge-cases.

For every usual use-case ember will keep your DOM in sync with your JS state automatically. So you have to fix your JS state, never the DOM directly.

Also even if you *could* replace your DOM, this wouldn't help with your problem, since your JS state would still contain the old data.

Comment: I did have the idea of putting all the form data into an object like userData, but I was having issues with clearing it. I think the root of my problem is I am using Materialize to put the component into a modal, and it is causing the component to act weird in some situations. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!